# SparkException: Can't zip RDDs with unequal numbers of partitions: List(2, 1)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Possible steps to reproduce：

1. Run spark.sql multiple times, get DataFrame list [d1, d2, d3, d4]
2. Combine DataFrame list [d1, d2, d3, d4] to a DataFrame d5 by calling Dataset#unionByName
3. Run `d5.groupBy("c1").pivot("c2").agg(concat_ws(", ", collect_list("value")))`，produce DataFrame d6
4. DataFrame d6 join another DataFrame d7
5. Call function like `count` to trigger spark job
6. Exception happend

stack trace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage.executeChildStages(QueryStage.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage.prepareExecuteStage(QueryStage.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage.executeCollect(QueryStage.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2836)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3441)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2836)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't zip RDDs with unequal numbers of partitions: List(2, 1)**
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsBaseRDD.getPartitions(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.eagerExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStage.executeStage(QueryStage.scala:284)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage.doExecute(QueryStage.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(QueryStage.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(QueryStage.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionIdAndJobDesc(SQLExecution.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryStage.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStage$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryStage.scala:78)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
```

**There are three points to note：**

1. I've never called a method zip or anything like that
2. When I set the parameter "spark.sql.adaptive.enabled" to "false" , the error disappear
3. Others have encountered this problem：https://github.com/Intel-bigdata/spark-adaptive/issues/73
4. Spark Version: 2.4.7

**Unfortunately, I can't share all the code snippets. I removed some sensitive information, and then the code contained the main execution logic.**

**Another discovery is that if I use spark-shell instead of spark-submit to execute the task, even if the parameter "spark.sql.adaptive.enabled" is set to "true", the error disappear**

```
val tagTableId = "customer_tag"
val tagMeta = Map(
    "t1" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t1",
    "tagName" -> "t1",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    ),
    "t2" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t2",
    "tagName" -> "t2",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    ),
    "t3" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t3",
    "tagName" -> "t3",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    ),
    "t4" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t4",
    "tagName" -> "t4",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    ),
    "t5" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t5",
    "tagName" -> "t5",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "single"
    ),
    "t6" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t6",
    "tagName" -> "t6",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "single"
    ),
    "t7" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t7",
    "tagName" -> "t7",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    ),
    "t8" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t8",
    "tagName" -> "t8",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "single"
    ),
    "t9" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t9",
    "tagName" -> "t9",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "single"
    ),
    "t10" -> (
    "tagId" -> "t10",
    "tagName" -> "t10",
    "valueType" -> "String",
    "valueNumType" -> "multi"
    )
)
val textTagIds = new util.ArrayList[String]()
val numTagIds = new util.ArrayList[String]()
val dateTagIds = new util.ArrayList[String]()
val dateTimeTagIds = new util.ArrayList[String]()

tagMeta.foreach(item => {
    val tagId = item._1
    val valueType = item._2._3._2

    valueType match {
    case "String" =>
        textTagIds.add(tagId)
    case "Number" =>
        numTagIds.add(tagId)
    case "Date" =>
        dateTagIds.add(tagId)
    case "DateTime" =>
        dateTimeTagIds.add(tagId)
    case _ =>
        throw new RuntimeException(s"invalid valueType: $valueType")
    }
})

val identitySql = "SELECT _uid, _type, _value, row_number() over(partition by _uid, _type order by _value desc) as rn FROM customer_identity WHERE _type IN ('membership_id')"
var oneDs = spark.sql(identitySql)
oneDs.createOrReplaceTempView("u")
oneDs = spark.sql(s"SELECT _uid, _type, _value FROM u WHERE rn <= 1")
    .groupBy("_uid")
    .pivot("_type")
    .agg(collect_list("_value").as("_value"))
oneDs.createOrReplaceTempView("u")

var textFrame: DataFrame = null
var numFrame: DataFrame = null
var dateFrame: DataFrame = null
var datetimeFrame: DataFrame = null

if (textTagIds.nonEmpty) {
    val tagIdsText = textTagIds.mkString("', '")
    val sql = s"SELECT _profile_id, tag_id, _value_text AS value, _weight AS weight FROM $tagTableId WHERE tag_id IN ('$tagIdsText')"
    textFrame = spark.sql(sql)
}

if (numTagIds.nonEmpty) {
    val tagIdsText = numTagIds.mkString("', '")
    val sql = s"SELECT _profile_id, tag_id, _value_num AS value, _weight AS weight FROM $tagTableId WHERE tag_id IN ('$tagIdsText')"
    numFrame = spark.sql(sql)
}

if (dateTagIds.nonEmpty) {
    val tagIdsText = dateTagIds.mkString("', '")
    val sql = s"SELECT _profile_id, tag_id, _value_date AS value, _weight AS weight FROM $tagTableId WHERE tag_id IN ('$tagIdsText')"
    dateFrame = spark.sql(sql).withColumn("value", date_format(col("value"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
}

if (dateTimeTagIds.nonEmpty) {
    val tagIdsText = dateTimeTagIds.mkString("', '")
    val sql = s"SELECT _profile_id, tag_id, _value_date AS value, _weight AS weight FROM $tagTableId WHERE tag_id IN ('$tagIdsText')"
    datetimeFrame = spark.sql(sql).withColumn("value", date_format(col("value"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
}

var tagFrame: DataFrame = textFrame

if (tagFrame == null) {
    tagFrame = numFrame
} else if (numFrame != null) {
    tagFrame = tagFrame.unionByName(numFrame)
}

if (tagFrame == null) {
    tagFrame = dateFrame
} else if (dateFrame != null) {
    tagFrame = tagFrame.unionByName(dateFrame)
}

if (tagFrame == null) {
    tagFrame = datetimeFrame
} else if (datetimeFrame != null) {
    tagFrame = tagFrame.unionByName(datetimeFrame)
}

val structType = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("tag_id", StringType),
    StructField("tag_name", StringType)
))
val rows = tagMeta.map(item => {
    val tagId = item._1
    val tagName = item._2._2._2
    RowFactory.create(tagId, tagName.replace("'", "\\'"))
}).toList
val tagMetaFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, structType)
tagFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("t")
tagMetaFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("m")

var sql = s"SELECT t._profile_id AS `_profile_id`, t.tag_id, m.tag_name, t.value, t.weight FROM t JOIN m ON t.tag_id = m.tag_id"
var dataFrame = spark.sql(sql)

dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("t")
sql = s"SELECT u.*, t.* FROM t LEFT JOIN u ON t._profile_id = u._uid"
dataFrame = spark.sql(sql).drop("_uid")
dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("t")

val orderedColumns = Array(s"`_profile_id`") ++ dataFrame.columns.filter(column => column != "_profile_id").map(column => s"`$column`")
sql = s"select ${orderedColumns.mkString(",")} from t"
dataFrame = spark.sql(sql)
val total = dataFrame.count()

println(total)
```

Comment: Your summary is good but the data is likely the cause of your issue.  (Meaning this likely works on small subsets of the data but on the entire set it fails.)  It's good information to know that the optimization engine is likely not making a good decision.
Can you share the query plan for both runs?(with and without spark.sql.adaptive.endabled)  This would likely help to understand where the issue 'could' be.

Comment: (FYI you aren't calling zip on RDDS, under the hood spark is trying to use an optimization that's failing.)

Comment: Can you show the complete code pls?

Comment: I am sorry that I can only provide the code related to the main logic. And I have added this part of the code to the question

Comment: Hard to work out what is going on, but my answer stands.

Comment: the final test is always in general spark-submit.

Comment: You are right! I only use spark-shell for testing purposes

Comment: So I am a little surprised. The logic is irrefutable if you know anything about Spark. SO, did you solve it?

Comment: No. I can't do anything other than change leave `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = false`

Comment: So that is what the 2 answers told you. You awarded nothing when you had lost the points anyway. It's these situations that make people like me less inclined to be involved with SO in future.

Comment: Ok. I just don't think the answers are not so helpful, after all, I want to solve the problem by not setting parameters

Comment: So the fact that a bug exists and cannot be circumvented. Interesting

Comment: The points have disappeared, I have do not know how to reward you

Comment: Or the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptive Query Execution, AQE, is a layer on top of Spark Catalyst which will modify the Spark Execution plan on the fly. It is a bug in AQE, clearly, for the version of Spark you are running.
Set AQE out.

> zip works with RDD partitions when all RDDs have same number of
> partitions, else you get an error. That's a given.
>
> - If you did not issue zip yourself in your code,
>
>   - and with AQE turned off there is no issue,
>
>     - then if AQE is turned on AND this error is gotten,
>
>       - then by definition AQE is doing something to optimize that is causing this bug to occur.

Comment: Do you mean that this issue has been fixed in a higher version of spark? I'm currently using version 2.4.7, which is already EOL

Comment: Possibly but as u do not provide all code I cannot confirm. But it may still be a bug.

Comment: Please provide full code.

Comment: I am sorry that I can only provide the code related to the main logic. And I have added this part of the code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Spark is selecting an optimization (spark.sql.adaptive.enabled) that it should not be. You should run this query with `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = false` as you are already doing.  There may be [settings](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) that you could adjust that would work for you to run this with spark.sql.adaptive.enabled set to true work. But do you need to optimize this query and do you know what corner case you are hitting?  I suggest until it's require to optimize that you just leave `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = false`.